# jQuery hasClass for any other attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hasClass is useful when I want to check if the element has some class. I want to do the same check for some other attribute. For example, I use

```
<div id="nav" data-available-for="users administrators guests"></div>
```

and want to check if this div is available for users. So, I would do it like

```
$('#nav').hasAttributeValue('data-available-for', 'users')
```

Are there any existing beautiful tiny solutions for this?

Comment: This seems like an extremely bad way to implement User Access Control.

Comment: Actually it is just an example to better understand my needs. I am not going to use it for user access control =).

Comment: In that case , i suspect that you are solving the problem from the wrong end. Using event delegation and checking attribute of target would be much better way for doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to explode strings or use indexOf. jQuery has a complete set of css-selectors build in and so you can use attribute-selectors.

you can combine `.is()` and attribute-selectors:

```
if( $('#nav').is('[data-available-for~="users"]') ) { ..
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
$('#nav').attr('data-available-for').indexOf('users') != -1
```

You can make a jquery helper out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
if ($('#nav').attr('data-available-for').split(' ').indexOf('users') != -1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Similarly, you can set attributes by passing a new value for the attribute as the second argument:

```
$('#nav').attr('data-available-for', 'users'); // data-available-for="users"
```

Comment: will never be true for `== users` based on example

Comment: You're correct. I've updated my answer to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of CSS Selector:

```
if ($("#nav[data-available-for~=user]").length) {
    // is available for 'user'
}
```

Or if you prefer have the element not mixed with the condition:

```
if ($("#nav").filter("[data-available-for~=user]").length) {
    // is available for 'user'
}
```

Of course you can build a function on top of it that makes it more readable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use some native javascript before falling back on a library.

```
<div id='strawberry-plant' data-fruit='12'></div>

<script>
var plant = document.getElementById('strawberry-plant');

//'Getting' data-attributes using getAttribute
var fruitCount = plant.getAttribute('data-fruit'); // fruitCount = '12'

// 'Setting' data-attributes using setAttribute
plant.setAttribute('data-fruit','7'); // Pesky birds
</script>
```

Where it's implemented you can use the dataset attribute on the serialized DOM object

```
<div id='sunflower' data-leaves='47' data-plant-height='2.4m'></div>

<script>
// 'Getting' data-attributes using dataset 
var plant = document.getElementById('sunflower');
var leaves = plant.dataset.leaves; // leaves = 47;

// 'Setting' data-attributes using dataset
var tallness = plant.dataset.plantHeight; // 'plant-height' -> 'plantHeight'
plant.dataset.plantHeight = '3.6m';  // Cracking fertiliser
</script>
```

additionally you can use some really powerful selecting with querySelectorAll like this

```
<script>
// Select all elements with a 'data-flowering' attribute
document.querySelectorAll('[data-flowering]');

// Select all elements with red leaves
document.querySelectorAll('[data-foliage-colour="red"]');
</script>
```

querySelectorAll() is supported by almost 90% of people online according to caniuse.com
http://caniuse.com/queryselector

and that is just the start.  check out the full power of css3 query selectors here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors